# Signalr java client Reconnect event doesn't work android studio

Tags: java, android, signalr, signalr.client

I have an instance of my signalr in my android application, this is signalr code:

```
public class HubConnectionFactory {

private static String serverUrl = "http://xxxx.example.com/";

private static HubConnectionFactory mInstance= null;
private HubConnection mConnection;
private HubProxy mHub;

protected HubConnectionFactory(){}

public static synchronized HubConnectionFactory getInstance(){
    if(null == mInstance){
        mInstance = new HubConnectionFactory();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public HubConnection getHubConnection() {
    return mConnection;
}

public HubProxy getHub() {
    return mHub;
}

public SignalRFuture<Void> connect() {
    final SignalRFuture<Void> future = new SignalRFuture<Void>();
    createObjects(future);

    return future;
}

private void createObjects(final SignalRFuture<Void> future) {


    mConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl, "version=1.0.0.0", true, new Logger() {

        @Override
        public void log(String message, LogLevel level) {
            if (level == LogLevel.Critical) {
                Log.d("TAG", level.toString() + ": " + message);
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        mHub = mConnection.createHubProxy("ChatHub");
    } catch (InvalidStateException e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Error getting creating proxy: " + e.toString());
        future.triggerError(e);
    }

    SignalRFuture<Void> connectionFuture = mConnection.start();

    mConnection.connected(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            future.setResult(null);
        }
    });
    connectionFuture.done(new Action<Void>() {

        @Override
        public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
            future.setResult(null);
        }
    });

    connectionFuture.onError(new ErrorCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            future.triggerError(error);
        }
    });

    mConnection.error(new ErrorCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Connection error: " + error.toString());

            if (!future.isDone()) {
                future.triggerError(error);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void disconnect() {
    mHub = null;
    mConnection.stop();
}
```

}

This is my activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        HubConnectionFactory hub2 = HubConnectionFactory.getInstance();
        hub2.connect();

        HubsConectionEvents();

      ....
    }

    private void HubsConectionEvents() {
        HubConnection conn = HubConnectionFactory.getInstance().getHubConnection();
        conn.connectionSlow(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection is slow and may fail...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        conn.reconnected(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection is reconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        conn.reconnecting(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection is reconnecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I just don't know why my signalr never activate my reconnecting and reconnected events, i want that signalr client reconnect immediately is disconnected and show that message.

How can i do that?

Comment: Try using `mTransport = new LongPollingTransport(mConnection.getLogger());` instead of `ServerSentEventsTransport`

Comment: Carlos have you found any solution